# Custom content type columns not getting displayed in document information panel

Tags: 2007, content-type, document-info-panel

I created a new content type "Sales Proposal" inheriting from Document content type, which has a few required columns, and added it to my document library. However, when I create a new Sales Proposal document, it does not show the Document information Panel in word.

However, when I create a simple Document, it shows me the DIM. I did check the

```
Always show Document Information Panel on document open and initial save for this content type
```

checkbox, but in-vain. Any help on how to associate / show columns in DIP for Sales Proposal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I was able to resolve this issue. Basically I was trying to use a .dotx file (Word 2013 Template file) as a template for my Content Type. I later used a .doc file and all worked as expected with the Document Information Panel getting displayed.